# Connecting to CentOS Server from outside fails if server has been idle

Tags: networking, centos6

I got a strange problem with the network connection of a Centos 6 server: 
From LAN everything works as expected (SSH, httpd) but outside connections fail if the server has been idle for a few minutes.
After sending a ping from another computer over lan, outside connections work as long as the server isn't idle. Some minutes later the server stops responding again.

The router configuration/port forwarding should be ok (connecting to a nas in the same network never failed) and over lan there haven't been any problems.

Does anyone know what i could have missed in the configuration that causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Check the connectivity between your server and its default gateway:

- do you see the MAC of the server in the gateway's ARP table? Is it the correct MAC?
- do you see the MAC of the gateway in the servers' ARP table? Is it the correct MAC?
- are other hosts experiencing the same issues?
- does a "clear arp-cache" or similar on the default gateway temporarily solves the issue?
- if the default gateway is a Cisco router, is CEF functioning as expected (if enabled)?

Comment: I checked the MACs  and cleared the arp cache, but no change so far...

Comment: i also didn't find any similar issues on other hosts

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a network element which drops idle connections when you connect from outside. You can work around this by adding keep alive to your ssh_config:

```
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 1000
```